# What anime is this figure of a white girl from?

Tags: merchandise

[image]

What anime is this girl from? I found this on Facebook and I'm just curious. Thanks.

Comment: From KanColle, one of the ships girl of the Abyss (the antagonist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is from [**Kantai Collection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantai_Collection).

> Kantai Collection (艦隊これくしょん Kantai Korekushon, lit. "Fleet Collection", subtitled as "Combined Fleet Girls Collection"), abbreviated as KanColle (艦これ KanKore), is a Japanese free-to-play web browser game developed by Kadokawa Games

The game was adapted into a [TV anime series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantai_Collection_%28anime%29) in Spring 2015 season.

The girl the figure is modeled (including her pose) after one of the Abyssal Bosses, [Aircraft Carrier Princess](http://kancolle.wikia.com/wiki/Aircraft_Carrier_Princess)

[image: Aircraft Carrier Princess]

Comment: Wow. this really answered my question. Thanks